# Distributing iOS App to non-employees

Tags: ios, distribute

I am developing an app that I would like some people to download it. Specifically, the people who attend my event. I've looked into the different ways of doing that, and I couldn't find how to do it. Is there a way to do it other than the App Store? Like a download link or an email attachment?

Scenario: I have an event taking place at some venue. People who attend must download an app before entering the place.

Comment: what is wrong with just submit to appstore?

Comment: @user523234, I don't want to care about Apple reviewing the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) or the [iOS Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

**TestFlight**

With TestFlight, you can let people 'test' your app. You can setup up to 25 internal testers and 1000 external testers to test your app.

Maybe it isn't exactly, what you are looking for, but it's the cheapest way.

They then can download the [TestFlight](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8)-app and will see the apps which they are invited as beta-testers. It's a very easy and nice possibility, because you also can update your app and the testers will receive updates.

[Check this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2) how to make a proper setup to do that.

**iOS Enterprise Program**

With this special program which costs 300$/year you can install your apps within your enterprise. But your company must be a company with a D-U-N-S number to apply. Check the [details](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) on the apple website.

Comment: But is this a good practice? As in, I don't see the users (or event attendees) as testers.

Comment: I've added another possibility to my answer. The iOS Enterprise Program. But it costs 300$ and I'm not sure, if your company applies to the conditions. But IMHO there are no other options beside these two which fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Diawi.com for that matter.

PROS:
1. Easy to use. Just drag the IPA file and the Provisioning Profile to the upload box. Wait for it to get uploaded. Generate Link. Send the link to your intended downloaders. They can download it super easy and fast.
2. No need to pass the app review in Apple.

CONS:
Few Users can download. Only the registered devices in your Apple Developer account can download the app which is limited to 100 and is renewable only for once a year.

If you intend this app for people not more than 100, use this. Otherwise use TestFlight that is already integrated in itunesconnect. The cons only is that the app needs to pass the review. Pros, up to 1000 people can download it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The main issue with this is that users have to send you their device ids ahead of time so the profile can be generated.